# How to Make API calls in express server

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I am trying to make a get request in an express server, currently the server simply prints all post requests and it works fine up to that, the issue is when GET request is made the response is returned as 'undefined'

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config = require("./config")[env];

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const hostname = config.server.host;
const port = config.server.port;

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);

  axios
    .get("https://reqres.in/api/products/3")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
});

app.listen(port, hostname, () =>
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`)
);
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any listener for `get` like you have it for `post`

Comment: Which API you are calling ? as currently there is only **POST** route available

Comment: An API makes POST requests to this express server ( ie a webhook), and i want to make a GET request after that API makes a POST request

Comment: @Sim Sadrowps X I executed this piece of code `axios
    .get("https://reqres.in/api/products/3")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });`  its excuted and printing the result, so what you are expecting???

Comment: sorry, for me i get 'undefined' response

Comment: @Subburaj https://ibb.co/TPTK6qr

Comment: @Sim Sadrowps X As I posted in the answer try for `.catch(error => { console.log(error); })` and see some error is printing

Answer (score 0):

Use [Postman](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/sending_the_first_request/) to send Api calls to the server. I am attaching the link down below.

- Install Postman chrome extension, if you're using chrome.
- Use the Localhost:port server and post method and add variable to post your query

Hope this helps.

Moreover, Just add this tweak in your code and listen on a proper localhost,

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config = require("./config")[env];

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const hostname = config.server.host;
const port = config.server.port;

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);

  axios
    .get("https://reqres.in/api/products/3")
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
});

app.listen(1337, function(){
  console.log('Express listening on port', this.address().port);
});
```

Comment: ive updated my answer, try to create the server locally and test it

Comment: Thanks, but i dont need to make an endpoint for get requests in my server
What i need is to make a GET request to another API, when my server gets a POST request on path /

Comment: I think that pretty much answers your own question. I am using this link https://reqres.in/api/products/3 and it's returning {"data":{"id":3,"name":"true red","year":2002,"color":"#BF1932","pantone_value":"19-1664"}} instead of undefined. Just Hard refresh your app.

Comment: i dont get that json object, i get undefined with in the app

Comment: Clean your cache of web browser. Try again code is working fine.

Comment: not running from browser, running on cli  
```node index.js```

Answer (score 0):

Executed the below code

```
    axios .get("https://reqres.in/api/products/3") 
.then(response => { console.log(response); }) 
.catch(error => { console.log(error.response); })
```

Its executed and working fine.

My Guess is that in your case its going to catch block

Change the following line

```
.catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
```

TO

```
.catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

And see whether some error is printing.No response object is assigned to error, that may be u r receiving `undefined`

Comment: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  port: 443,
  config:
   { url: 'https://reqres.in/api/products/3',
     method: 'get',
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.0' },
     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     timeout: 0,
     adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],

Comment: the get request works fine on postman  its only when i run the index.js file from cli i get the error

Comment: @Sim Sadrowps X I ran the above code in cmd prompt only as `node file.js` its executed